# 6, 10, 12, and 15 go out for dinner

Tags: mathematics

> 6 buys drinks and says "I'm 1/2 Israeli and 1/2 Chinese."
>   15 orders appetizers for everyone and says "I'm 1/2 American and 1/2 Chinese."
>   12 orders the main course for everyone and says "I'm 2/3 Israeli and 1/3 Chinese."

What parts Israeli, Chinese, and American is 10?

Comment: Is this really a math puzzle, or is there some word-play or lateral thinking involved?

Comment: Looks like math to me @Gamow

Comment: The nitpicker in me is just dying to point out that "2/3 Israeli and 1/3 Chinese" is impossible. Okay, I'm done, carry on enjoying the puzzle.

Comment: Because 7 ate 9

Comment: @stacey are you sure of that? You go up high enough on the family tree and say instead of 1024 10th generation parents there were only 1023, 341 of them Chinese, 682 of them Israeli perhaps by descent or religion as the country didn't exist then. Of course you can rewind time enough to arrive to the ancient kingdoms and then it'll certainly be possible... unless I misunderstand your problem.

Comment: 1/3 is possible if you're a time-traveler who's your own grandparent.

Comment: @chx: If there are only 1023 10-th generation ancestors it must be because one of them counts twice. That makes the guy at the bottom an inbred abomination, of course, but does _not_ give him any fraction that doesn't have a power of two in the denominator.

Comment: @stacey, what if you consider donors and surrogates?

Comment: "Because 7 ate 9" * *pulls the trigger* *

Answer (score 26):

10 is

> $\frac{1}{2}$ Israeli, $\frac{1}{2}$ American

Reasoning:

> The prime $2$ is Israeli, the prime $3$ is Chinese, and the prime $5$ is American.
>  Then $6=2\cdot3$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ Israeli and $\frac{1}{2}$ Chinese.
>  Then $15=3\cdot5$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ American and $\frac{1}{2}$ Chinese.
>  Then $12=2\cdot2\cdot3$ is $\frac{2}{3}$ Israeli and $\frac{1}{3}$ Chinese.
>
>  Consequently $10=2\cdot5$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ Israeli and $\frac{1}{2}$ American.

Answer (score 7):

A different answer that's probably not what you intended, but:

> If you take the numbers' statements to mean the system of equations:
>  
>  $6  = (I + C) / 2$
>  $15 = (A + C) / 2$
>  $12 = (2I + C) / 3$
>  
>  Then $A=42$, $C=-12$, and $I=24$.

There are an infinite number of ways to combine these to form the number 10, but if you continue the pattern of each number being a mixture of exactly two nationalities, then

> $10$ is $7/18$ Chinese and $11/18$ Israeli.

Comment: In the two nationality case, this system also allows for 10 to be 11/27 American and 16/27 Chinese. (Or, as you pointed out, some mixture of the three, where the percentage of Chinese is between 7/18 and 16/27).

Answer (score 5):

10 is

> 1/2 American and 1/2 Israeli.

because

> Israeli -> 2 
>  Chinese -> 3 
>  American -> 5 
>  The fractions are the fraction of the numbers' prime factorization from the above mapping. So 10 = 2*5 has two prime factors. Half are 2 (Israeli) and half are 5 (American).

Answer (score 4):

10 is

> 1/2 Israeli and 1/2 American.

Explanation:

> This problem refers to the prime factorization of the different numbers. "Israeli" corresponds to the power of $2$ in the factorization, "Chinese" corresponds to the power of $3$, and "American" corresponds to the power of $5$; each exponent is then divided by the sum of the exponents of all prime factors to obtain the fraction. $6 = 2^1 \cdot 3^1$, $15 = 3^1 \cdot 5^1$, $12 = 2^2 \cdot 3^1$, and $10 = 2^1 \cdot 5^1$, giving the fractions from the question and the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> $6=2*3$, $15=3*5$ and $12=2^2*3$, so "Israeliness" is the ratio of the exponent of 2 to the sum of the exponents in the prime factor expansion of the given number. Same with Chineseness and 3, Americanness and 5. Therefore, 10 is 1/2 Israeli and 1/2 American.